# imap_unordered() hangs up if iterable throws an error

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Consider the file `sample.py` contains the following code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def sample_worker(x):
    print "sample_worker processes item", x
    return x

def get_sample_sequence():
    for i in xrange(2,30):
        if i % 10 == 0:
            raise Exception('That sequence is corrupted!')
        yield i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(24)
    try:
        for x in pool.imap_unordered(sample_worker, get_sample_sequence()):
            print "sample_worker returned value", x
    except:
        print "Outer exception caught!"
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "done"
```

When I execute it, I get the following output:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 338, in _handle_tasks
    for i, task in enumerate(taskseq):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 278, in <genexpr>
    self._taskqueue.put((((result._job, i, func, (x,), {})
  File "C:\Users\renat-nasyrov\Desktop\sample.py", line 10, in get_sample_sequence
    raise Exception('That sequence is corrupted!')
Exception: That sequence is corrupted!
```

After that, application hangs up. How can I handle the situation without hangups?

Comment: Your indentation is wrong…

Comment: I stepped through the code with the debugger, and it worked as expected. However, when I execute it I get the behaviour you describe. So maybe there is a concurrency issue in imap_unordered?

Comment: The difference between when it works and when it does not work is in line 644 in pool.py: 'if self._index == self._length:' either it raises StopIteration as a next step and everything is fine, or it jumps to 'self._cond.wait(timeout)' and hangs. You could check if you can set the timeout somehow as a workaround.

Comment: Could you add some details about your actual use-case? The imap functions do not seem to handle exceptions gracefully (I would expect them to be reraised). In your example using a generator does not make sense. Once it throws an exception, you cannot get new items from it anymore. In your example you could easily use an other iterable object like a list.

Answer (score 2):

As septi mentioned your indentation is (still) wrong. Indent the yield statement so that i is within its scope. I am not entirely sure as to what actually happens in your Code, but yielding a variable that is out of scope does not seem like a good idea:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def sample_worker(x):
    print "sample_worker processes item", x
    return x

def get_sample_sequence():
    for i in xrange(2,30):
      if i % 10 == 0:
          raise Exception('That sequence is corrupted!')
      yield i # fixed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(24)
    try:
        for x in pool.imap_unordered(sample_worker, get_sample_sequence()):
            print "sample_worker returned value", x
    except:
        print "Outer exception caught!"
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print "done"
```

To handle exceptions in your generator, you may use a wrapper such as this one:

```
import logging
def robust_generator():
    try:
        for i in get_sample_sequence():
            logging.debug("yield "+str(i))
            yield i
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(e)
        raise StopIteration()
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've really missed that indent, but that's not the issue. The problem is that if generator raises an exception, the whole thing is hung up. You robust generator simply swallows the exception, resulting in partial sequence handling without any warning (except for log entry). In general case, this is not a desirable behavior. Ideally, it should throw a catchable exception.

Comment: The robust_generator converts the exception into a StopIteration Exception, which gets handled appropriately. Instead of raising StopIteration(), you can insert your error handling code. You can even ignore the Exception and retry, though I am not sure if you can simply continue getting items from a generator once it raised an exception.